# How to make the menu bar font bold for all users in window7?

Tags: windows-7, registry

I'm trying to make all the menu bar font [Bold] for all users in the machine. 
I tried to find a registry key for that but I couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS)` to change the `lfMenuFont`.

Comment: Thank you for your respons, but where can I find this?

Comment: Um, search MSDN for `SystemParametersInfo`, `SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS` and `lfMenuFont`?